# Stop Ajax Events in Drupal 7 Form

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal-7, dom-events

I'm faced to a Drupal 7 problem and its built-in ajax framework.
My fields are registered step by step when the user fills them and a final check is made when the form is submitted (without js this time). I'm using this `#ajax` callback for every field except my submit button:

```
$form['myfield'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#default_value' => 'test',
        '#title' => 'test',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '_form_submit_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'name-error-icon-container',
            'method' => 'html',
            'effect' => 'none',
            'progress' => array(
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        )
);

//EDIT: My callback as asked

function _form_submit_callback($form, &$form_state)
{
            
    form_state_values_clean($form_state); //Remove unuseful values from $form_state['values']    
    $hash = $form_state['values']['hash'];
    $currData = db_select('my_custom_table', 'rms')
        ->condition('hash', $hash)
        ->forUpdate(true)
        ->fields('rms')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
    if (is_array($currData)) {
        if ($currData != $form_state['values']) {
            $form_state['values']['updated_at'] = time();

            $num_updated = db_update('my_custom_table')
                ->fields($form_state['values'])
                ->condition('hash', $hash)
                ->execute();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $form_state['values']['inserted_at'] = $form_state['values']['updated_at'] = time();
        db_insert('my_custom_table')
            ->fields($form_state['values'])
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

This allows me to know where the user is and which field has been completed.

Everything is working great until the last field. The user enters the field and changes the value. The field is only updated with an ajax query when the user leaves it.

So each time the user leaves a field, the _form_submit_callback function is invoked and my content is updated.

The problem comes when the user clicks the submit form button. Two update queries are sent, one with ajax by leaving the field and another one with the form submit function.

How could I prevent Drupal from sending ajax queries when I click my submit button? Is there a way to remove every single call or just disable ajax everywhere? I checked blur, change, focus events but nothing is working, it seems Drupal is using its own events. I saw a js object in my browser called Drupal.ajax, maybe I can do something with that ?

I'm on this for a few days now. I'm exhausted; If you have any idea ?

Comment: can you post your ajax and submit callbacks?

Comment: I posted my _form_submit_callback but I don't know how it will be useful. I don't have ajax callbacks. Drupal do the works alone.